# Как закрыть файл после отправки его на почту?

Tags: c#

У меня есть программа, каждые 30 секунд она записывает свои действия в файл .txt.
В `backgroundWorker` каждые 30 мин этот файл отправляется мне на почту, но после отправки при попытке записать данные в файл выходит ошибка "этот файл используется в другом потоке".
Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему.

Вот код отправки:

```cs
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("От кого", "Кому","Заголовок", "Текст сообщения");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
client.Port = 587;
System.Net.Mail.Attachment data = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(nameDoc); // nameDoc - переменная содержащая путь к файлу
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("логин", "пароль");
client.EnableSsl = true;
mail.Attachments.Add(data);
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: как идет запись в файл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Attachment` реализует `IDisposable`, попробуйте явно его уничтожать:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("От кого", "Кому","Заголовок", "Текст сообщения");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("логин", "пароль");
client.EnableSsl = true;

using (System.Net.Mail.Attachment data = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(nameDoc))
{
    mail.Attachments.Add(data);
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

А лучше уничтожайте целиком `MailMessage`:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru");
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("логин", "пароль");
client.EnableSsl = true;

using (var mail = new MailMessage("От кого", "Кому","Заголовок", "Текст сообщения"))
{
    var data = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(nameDoc));
    mail.Attachments.Add(data);
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Comment: Лучше тогда сделать Dispose для MailMessage.

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, глянул - он уничтожает все аттачт